# Phalcon\Mvc\Model::beforeCreate() method

Tags: php, phalcon

If i try to save model with date_created field defined in beforeCreate() method, it does not save it:

```
class TestEntity extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public function beforeCreate()
    {
        $this->date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    /**
     * Returns source table name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'test_entity';
    }
}
```

Controller action context:

```
$test = new TestEntity();
$test->name = 'test';
var_dump($contact->save()); // gives false
var_dump($contact->getMessages()); // says date_created is not defined
```

Comment: Is the field in `test_entity` table called date_created?

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos it was necessary to use little bit different method, beforeValidationOnCreate(), as twistedxtra said. Thank you :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to assign the creation date before the null validation is performed:

```
<?php

class TestEntity extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public function beforeValidationOnCreate()
    {
        $this->date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    /**
     * Returns source table name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'test_entity';
    }
}
```

Comment: What about modified_at? If I want to update the modified_at when the record is updated? Thank you

Comment: @piavgh you can use the `beforeUpdate()` method - or `beforeValidationOnUpdate()` method if the fields you're changing will go through validation.

You can find more info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html